# CakePHP Fetch Assoc equivalent for printing out values in array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp

with just PHP / MySQL, I use this:

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["field"] . "<br>";
}
```

Not sure how to do this in PHP?

have my find statement:

```
       $row = $this->Account->find('all',
        array(
            'fields' => array(
                'email',
                'password'
            ),
            'order' => array(
                'checktime ASC'
            ),
            'limit' => $amt
        )
    );
```

basically what would $row be equal to, in order to loop through and print all values?

I'm guessing something like this:

```
foreach ($row as &$value) {
echo $row['Account']['email'];
```

}

but that returns error that the index 'Account' doesn't exist.

so I imagine I would need to make this happen somehow

```
echo $row['0']['Account']['email']
```

where 0 increments (could do a index++ type thing, but then how would I know I'm at end of the array?)

want to learn the RIGHT way to do things--but also wanted to jump right in and start messing w/code.  very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how your data is formatted but you can tell how you need to format your foreach using....

```
print_r($row);
```

**OR**

```
var_dump($row);
```

**You can use:**

```
foreach ( $row as $value ) 
  echo $row[0]['Account']['email']
```

**OR**

If the index increments

```
$i = 0;
  foreach ( $row as $value ) {
    echo $row[$i]['Account']['email'];
    $i++;
  }
```

Comment: the index does increment, but for some reason I thought I would run into issues not knowing how many rows.  don't know what I was thinking lol.  Now just realize it will exit the loop after it runs out of row :\.  thanks for your reply!